# Prove that a continuous real-valued function on a closed interval in $E^2$ cannot be one-one

Tags: real-analysis

I am working through Rosenlicht's Introduction to Analysis. Could someone help me with this problem? I am at a loss how to attack it. Thanks a lot.

> Prove that a continuous real-valued function on a closed interval in $E^2$ cannot be one-one.

($E^2$ is the 2D Euclidean space)

Comment: Your question seems incomplete.

Comment: @JackyChong Could you explain more? I transcribed from the book and the statement seems complete to me.